# Pretty function in Matlab not showing proper results

Tags: matlab

Does anybody understand why the pretty function is printing an equation this way

```
      exp(pi k i) (pi k i - 1)        exp(-pi k i) (pi k i + 1)
  ------------------------ + #1   ------------------------- - #1
              2                                2
             k                                k
- ----------------------------- + ------------------------------
               2 pi                            2 pi
```

where

```
            /   pi k i \ / pi k i     \
         exp| - ------ | | ------ + 1 |
            \      2   / \    2       /
   #1 == ------------------------------
                        2
                       k
```

Isn't #1 supposed to get cancelled?

Thanks

Comment: Two negative terms don't cancel each other.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow @juan-diego. As @ben-voigt says in your comment, two negative terms doesn't cancel each other. Let me explain this:

You have the following equation:

```
-(A + #1)     (B - #1)     - A -#1 + B -#1       B - A - 2*#1
---------- + ---------- = ------------------ = -------------- 
   2 pi         2 pi              2 pi              2 pi
```

You can try to use the function `simplify` and see if this happens.